# Form within PHP not showing up on page

Tags: php, html

I have a form that I am trying to use to reset passwords. I can get it to send the email out and I can click the link, but when I click the link all I get is the header. My form is not showing. I am *extremely* new to all of this. Any help will be much appreciated. I did search through some other posts, but none of them seemed to get me any closer to the right answer. Everything seems to work as it should, I just can't get my form to display so that I can enter the information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Reset Password Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"><h2>Reset New Password Here</h2>

<?php
if($_GET['email'] && $_GET['token']) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");

    // Check connection
    if($conn === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. "
            . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $token = $_GET['token'];

    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `reset_link_token`='".$token."' and `emailaddress`='".$email."';");

    $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        if($row['expiry_date'] <= $current_date) { ?>
            <form action="update-password.php" method="post">
                <input name="email" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
                <input name="reset_link_token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
                <div class="form-group"><label for="new-password">Password</label>
                    <input id="new-password" name="password" type="password" /></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input id="confirm-password" name="confirm_password" type="password" /></div>
                <input class="submit-btn" name="submit" type="submit" />
            </form>
<?php }
    } else {
        echo "This forget password link has been expired";
    }
}
?>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The message about the password link expiring is in the wrong `else` block. It should be in the `else` for `if($row['expiry_date'] <= $current_date)`, not `if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)`

Comment: Use `var_dump($row['expiry_date'], $current_date)` and compare them.

Comment: Like this? </form>
<?php }
}
}else {
echo "This forget password link has been expired";
}
?>

Comment: No, you should have *less* `}`, so it matches the most recent `if`.

Comment: `</form> <?php } else { echo ... } } else { echo "email not found"; }`

Comment: I tried the second thing you mentioned and got error 500. I might have done it wrong too though...

Comment: You probably screwed up the brace balancing. Use an IDE with automatic balancing.

Comment: I think my problem is right here

Comment: if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if($row['expiry_date'] <= $current_date) { ?>

Comment: When you get a 500 error, there will be an error message in the server log. It will tell you exactly where the error is.

Comment: And from the terminal you can use `php -l filename.php`, it will check the syntax.

Comment: what terminal? I am afraid I do not know what you are talking about.

Comment: A Command Prompt window on Windows.

Comment: Changed a couple more things. Still only get the heading with no form.

Comment: So now that you've solved the syntax error, what's are the values of the variables when you `var_dump` them? Are they what you expect?

Comment: I tried the command prompt thing, but it didn’t work. 

I’m not sure how to use var_dump, but I’m looking it up. 

I just don’t understand why everything seems to work, but my form doesn’t show. If I could just get that form to show, I’m sure the rest of my password reset stuff will work.

Comment: The only reason the form wouldn't show is that the if condition isn't true. That's why you need to look at the variables.

Comment: Ok, I got the if condition to be true. The form displays! Now my next problem (which I believe is more syntax problems), when the new password is entered it updates the database with the token rather than the new password entered by the user.

Comment: Make sure you're saving `$_POST['password']`, not `$_POST['reset_link_token']`

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you for the help. I now have to try and figure out how to implement the security questions that I have the "user" set up during registration.

Comment: I should add that this is not a live website, this is something I am doing for school. I am not worried about security, like SQL injections and all that. I just want it to work.

Comment: You should still learn to do things the right way, even if it's not needed for this exercise.